# Deployment issue with HoloLens emulator in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I am trying to deploy and debug a UWP app from Visual Studio 2017 into a HoloLens emulator. The issue I am facing is that most of the times I am facing two different types of deployment errors:

- Remote Debugger Error

[image]

- Authentication Error
  [image]

The strange issue is that these do not happen always. Sometimes I am able to successfully run and debug the app but then most of the times I am getting the above errors.

Has anybody encountered similar situations or been in the same scenario and solved it? I have tried regular searches on google but could not find anything very relevant with the emulator. Please help.